# File Name Warning for C:\Program

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Since a few weeks I get the error message after login:

```
File Name Warning
There is a file of folder on your computer called "C:\Program" which
could cause certain applications to not function correctly. Renaming it
to "c:\Program1" would solve this problem. Would you like to rename
it now?

[ ] Don't perform this check at startup
```

[image: File Name Warning Screenshot]

Clicking the <kbd>Rename</kbd> button results in the error message

```
Folder In Use
The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in
another program
Close the folder or file and try again
```

[image: Folder In Use Screenshot]

Therefore I started Process Explorer and did a Handle search for `C:\Program`. Of course it finds a lot of items for `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`, so I sorted them by name. There is no handle listed for `C:\Program`.

[image: C:\Program in Process Explorer]

Next I assumed it might be a permission issue and tried to take ownership of the folder. Unfortunately this does not work as well. I get

```
 Error applying security
 An error occurred while applying security information to:
 C:\Program
 Access is denied.
```

[image: Error applying security screenshot]

followed by

```
Windows Security
Unable to set new owner on Program.
Access is denied.
```

[image: Unable to set new owner Screenshot]

The current owner is the administrators group and I am a member of that group. Checking the effective permissions, I have full control (all checkmarks checked). I can create files and delete files inside the folder.

There are no files inside the folder, neither in Explorer nor DOS (`dir /a`) nor Search Everything.

Some websites say I have malware, but I doubt that. I'm not visiting dangerous websites and I have an up to date virus scanner.

**How do I delete the C:\Program folder?**

Note: I don't have access to the BIOS, so can't boot from a CD drive or USB stick.

I know that I could disassemble the PC and connect the hard drive to a different PC, attach it as an external drive and then make changes to the disk. However, I'm looking for a built-in solution.

Comment: In your case, It maybe a virus or something like so...

Comment: You don’t necessarily need access to the firmware setup. Try F8, F11, F12 and the like when the POST screen shows. They usually trigger a boot device selection menu.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/706400/why-can-a-program-named-c-program-influence-other-programs with great explanation of the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried booting into Safe Mode to see if it makes a difference? This should help rule out third-party programs and shell extensions that could could be interfering.

To use Safe Mode, restart your computer and hold <kbd>F8</kbd> just before Windows starts to load.

Answer (score 3):

It could possibly be McAfee access protection keeping you from deleting the folder C:\Program\

1. Disable Access Protection.

   - Click Start, Programs, McAfee, VirusScan Enterprise, VirusScan Console.
   - Right-click Access Protection and select Disable.
   - Leave the Console open.
2. Delete the folder C:\Program\
3. Enable Access Protection.

   - Click Start, Programs, McAfee, VirusScan Enterprise, VirusScan Console.
   - Right-click Access Protection and select Enable.
   - Close the VirusScan console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to registry, you can try to add this file for automatic removal upon reboot. To do this:

1. Start -> Run
2. Type in regedit, and press ENTER
3. Goto
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
4. Create a new `Multi-String` value: `PendingFileRenameOperations`
5. Enter `\??\C:\Programs` as the data
6. Press `OK`
7. Right-click on the key, click `Modify Binary Data`
8. At the end of the hex string, add `0000` (4 zeros which represent an empty string)
9. Press OK
10. Restart your computer

Windows will try to remove the file upon restarting.

Source: http://blog.notfaqs.com/2007/10/registry-rename-file-on-reboot.html

Comment: In step 5 I can't enter the value like that. It only accepts the value `\??\\C:\Program`. Note the double backslash. The double backslash can be anywhere. In step 8 the value already has 4 zeros at the end, in fact 4 bytes of zeros which show up as 8 zeros `00 00 00 00`. That said, there seems to be a high risk on that method. Better double check with SysInternals PendMoves, but I don't know what the correct output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Like Process Explorer, it does not show the directory as being in use.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use some Linux on a USB drive (with ntfs-3g support), e.g. [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/). This way you don't have to hassle with Windows NTFS Security or any Trojan which might conceal the file from you.

1. Boot to Linux
2. [Mount your Windows partition with ntfs-3g](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Mounting_an_NTFS_partition_with_full_Read-Write_support)
3. Get into the GUI (for SysRescCD: Enter `startx` after bootup)
4. Open the File Explorer
5. Go to `/mnt/windows`
6. Find that `Program` file or folder and delete it
7. Exit the GUI
8. Type `halt` to shutdown Linux and your computer
9. Remove the USB drive and boot into your Windows

Comment: he says he cannot boot from anything due to bios restrictions

Comment: Then he maybe should get the person who has the BIOS password to remove that malicious file/folder.